# How do I print integer values without additional zeroes after comma by using cout in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, precision, cout, iomanip

Basically my code is about calculating equilateral triangle perimeter.
Given values are these:

```
3
2.5 3 5.15
```

First number defines how many triangles there are and the numbers in second line are each triangle's side length.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>+
using namespace std;

double Strik(double a);
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    double arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<arr[i]<<" "<<Strik(arr[i])<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
double Strik(double a){
double s  = ((a*a)*sqrt(3))/4;
 return s;
 }
```

Cout needs to be like this:

```
2.5 2.71
3 3.90
5.15 11.48
```

But I get this:

```
2.5 2.71
3.00 3.90
5.15 11.48
```

Please help

Comment: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/10147399)

Comment: You have to include `<iostream>`

Comment: the first `3` no trailing `0` but the second with fixedprecision `3.90` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818  I need to get `3` instead of `3.00` in the second `cout` line

Comment: yes, but you want `3.9` printed as `3.90` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 yeah

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::setprecision` specifies the maximum number of digits to use and if you want to get N digits all the time you need to use `std::fixed`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double a = 3.5;
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(4);
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And now the output is `3.5000`.

Opposite from `std::fixed` is `std::defaultfloat` and in the first column you need `std::defaultfloat` but in the second column you need `std::fixed` so this is the way to go for you:

```cpp
cout << defaultfloat << setprecision(2) << arr[i] << " ";
cout << fixed << Strik(arr[i]) << endl;
```

Check out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:16,endLineNumber:2,positionColumn:16,positionLineNumber:2,selectionStartColumn:16,selectionStartLineNumber:2,startColumn:16,startLineNumber:2),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccmath%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciomanip%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Adouble+Strik(double+a)%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++double+arr%5B5%5D+%3D+%7B1.2,+1.3,+1.4,+1.5,+1.6%7D%3B%0A++++for(int+i%3D0%3Bi%3C5%3Bi%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++++cout+%3C%3C+defaultfloat+%3C%3C+setprecision(2)+%3C%3C+arr%5Bi%5D+%3C%3C+%22+%22%3B%0A++++++++cout+%3C%3C+fixed+%3C%3C+Strik(arr%5Bi%5D)+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adouble+Strik(double+a)%7B%0A++++double+s++%3D+((a*a)*sqrt(3))/4%3B%0A++++return+s%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.85494633014216,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.145053669857845,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%232+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.145053669857845,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

**UPDATE**

If, as said in one of the comments, you want to output number 13.6, then you need to increase precision like this:

```cpp
cout << defaultfloat << setprecision(3) << arr[i] << " ";
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << Strik(arr[i]) << endl;
```

Comment: You haven't answered the OP's question.  They are looking to display the output numbers at their shortest form, subject to a maximum number of two digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @KrisW that's exactly what I explained in the second part of the answer, and that's exactly what the live demo does

Comment: But change arr[0] to 13.6 and see what happens...   You really wanted to display "14" there??

Comment: @KrisW then OP just needs to increase the precision

Comment: Increasing the precision will result in additional digits after the decimal point.    What they're looking to do cannot be done with iomanip.

Answer (score 3):

You can´t do this inside one `cout` statement only.

You´ll need a control statement before, which proofs if `Strik(arr[i])` is an integral value or not. With the C libraries which are included in the C++ standard libraries we can compare the return value of the `floorf()` function in the header of `math.h`, with the actual value of `Strik(arr[i])`, as condition of an if statement, like `if(floorf(Strik(arr[i])) == Strik(arr[i]))` to accomplish that task:

So the relative part of the program shall look like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(floorf(Strik(arr[i])) == Strik(arr[i]))
    {
       cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << arr[i] << " " << Strik(arr[i]) << endl;
    }

    else
    {
       cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << arr[i] << " " << Strik(arr[i]) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @KrisW In this case, Indeed, `3` can´t and **shouldn´t** be abbreviated. But that is not subject of the question. The OP wants to display a complete integer without floating-point precision by using `cout`. He said that the value is a straight `3`, not `3.00001`.

Comment: Your solution would display "3.00", not "3.00001". Try it.

I'd have expected a general solution, rather than one that works for the exact input values that were used an example.

Comment: @KrisW When I test it with `double v = 3.000000`, I´ll get the result of `3` not `3.00` with this technique. i don´t know why it is different by you. - *I'd have expected a general solution, rather than one that works for the exact input values that were used an example.*  - The OP asks for a method to show an *even* integer value which is of type `double`, like for example: `3.000000000` in the output of `cout` as `3`. The question is **not** about to convert an `double` value of f.e. `3.00000000001` to `3` nor to print it out as such.

Comment: I said double v = **3.00001** , not 3.00000.  The value being close to, but not exactly, an integer is important, because it shows the error you're making.  The inexactness of FP arithmetic often results in "near integer" values that are actually integers.  There are many pitfalls in presenting FP values to users, which is why, when calculations must be reported, we use multiple-precision arithmetic instead. Incidentally, the OP is also wrong in what they're asking for, but if "no '.00' on the numbers" is what they ask for, the answer should at least follow what they want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want with the standard C++ manipulators.

Your options are:

1. `<< std::fixed << std::precision(2) <<` sets the exact number of decimal places to 2

```
2.50 2.71
3.00 3.90
5.15 11.48
```

2. `<< std::precision(2) <<` sets the number of significant digits to 2

```
2.5 2.7
3 3.9
5.1 11
```

You might think that `std::setprecision(3)` is the answer to your problem, but watch what happens when you try to print 115.7 :

```
116
```

Oops.

If this is really important to you, the only way to achieve it (without the enormous hassle of writing an iostream manipulator) is to do the conversion from double-to-string yourself and post-process the results..

### Version 1: Trim all trailing zeros

```
#include <iostream>
#include <strstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


const std::string trim( double d )
{
   const int places=2;
   std::ostringstream out;
   out << std::setprecision(places) << std::fixed << d;
   std::string s = out.str(); // "3.19" or "5.00" or "212.70"
   s = s.substr( 0,  s.find_last_not_of( "0" )+1 );
   if ( s[s.size()-1]=='.') { s.erase(s.size()-1); }
   return s;
}

 ...

 cout<<trim(arr[i])<<" "<<trim(Strik(arr[i]))<<endl;
```

### Version 2: Trim ".00" from integers, leave all others in place

```
const std::string trim( double d )
{
   const int places=2;
   std::ostringstream out;
   out << std::setprecision(places) << std::fixed << d;
   std::string s = out.str(); // "3.19" or "5.00" or "212.70"
   if ( s[s.size()-1]=='0' && s[s.size()-2]=='0') { s.erase(s.size()-3); }
   return s;
}
```